# Calling a function from inside a function in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, function, google-apps-script

I'm having an issue in google apps script where my function variables are coming through as null. Am I missing something obvious here?

The variables are mostly IDs of fields in Google Forms that I later pull out. I had them hardcoded in and the script works fine. I pulled them out into another function because I want multiple triggers to run this same block of code, but each will have different IDs for the respective fields.

```
function initiateGeneralTest(e){

  let reviewName = 'test';
  let fieldClickId = '1.726545029E9';
  let fieldBirthYear = '1.706089792E9';
  let fieldRecommend = '1.080086258E9';
  let fieldRemoteReview = '5.28058257E8';
  let fieldFreetext = '9.40439086E8';

  sendFormData(e,reviewName,fieldClickId,fieldBirthYear,fieldRecommend,fieldRemoteReview,fieldFreetext);
}

//General - Test
function sendFormData(e,reviewName, fieldClickId, fieldBirthYear, fieldRecommend, fieldRemoteReview, fieldFreetext) {

  Logger.log(reviewName);
  Logger.log(fieldClickId);
  Logger.log(fieldBirthYear);
  Logger.log(fieldRecommend);
  Logger.log(fieldRemoteReview);
  Logger.log(fieldFreetext);

//Other Code
}
```

When I run this script via the trigger all the variables just return null, apart from e, which is the form response.

```
Jun 1, 2020, 2:39:13 PM Info    [object Object]
Jun 1, 2020, 2:39:13 PM Info    null
Jun 1, 2020, 2:39:13 PM Info    null
Jun 1, 2020, 2:39:13 PM Info    null
Jun 1, 2020, 2:39:13 PM Info    null
Jun 1, 2020, 2:39:13 PM Info    null
Jun 1, 2020, 2:39:13 PM Info    null
```

Comment: Are you sure you're triggering initiateGeneralTest and not sendFormData? Cause this looks like the case.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. How do you set the trigger?